# why could a rig need "bone end" bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a rig where the end of most bones has a bone on the end that does literally nothing and its labeled `BoneName`_end and I have no clue if there is any scenario where I would need that or not. [would appreciate it if someone could check it out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f10eMHeTp_JEseVGFyLwoF9gtTZpONAr/view?usp=sharing)

here is a picture with the _end bones selected

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some 3D softwares don't use bones as rigging system, they use "Joints" instead. You can think of a joint as the Head of our bones (which acts as pivot point of rotation and scaling).

As long as you work with softwares using bones (like Blender, Unity, Unreal Engine) there's no need of end bones, you can delete them.

If you were to export your rig to a joints based software, and then reimport it into a bone based software, there would be a missing information about where exactly would be located the tail of the last bone of the chain, and that's the information carried by end bones.

Even if you have deleted end bones, when you export an FBX from Blender you can tick the option "Add Leaf Bones", to recreate them.